# How to interpolate only over a specific window?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset that follows a weekly indexation, and a list of dates that I need to get interpolated data for. For example, I have the following df with weekly aggregation:

```
data           value
1/01/2021       10
7/01/2021       10
14/01/2021      10
28/01/2021      10
```

and a list of dates that do not coincide with the df indexed dates, for example:

```
list_dates = [12/01/2021, 13/01/2021 ...]
```

I need to get what the interpolated values would be for every date on the `list_dates` but within a given window (for ex: using only 4 values in the df to calculate to interpolation, split between before and after --> so the 2 first dates before the list date and the 2 first dates after the list date).

To get the interpolated value of the list date 12/01/2021 in the list, I would need to use:

```
1/1/2021
7/1/2021
14/1/2021
28/1/2021
```

The output would then be:

```
data           value
1/01/2021       10
7/01/2021       10
12/01/2021      10
13/01/2021      10
14/01/2021      10
28/01/2021      10
```

I have successfully coded an example of this but it fails for when there are multiple NaNs consecutively (for ex: 12/01 and 13/01). I also can't concat the interpolated value before running the next one in the list, as that would be using the interpolated date to calc the new interpolated date (for ex: using 12/01 to calculate 13/01).

Any advice on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `interpolate` to get expected outcome but before you have to prepare your dataframe like below.

I slightly modify your input data to show you interpolation with datetimeindex (`method='time'`):

```
# Input data
df = pd.DataFrame({'data': ['1/01/2021', '7/01/2021', '14/01/2021', '28/01/2021'],
                   'value': [10, 10, 17, 10]})
list_dates = ['12/01/2021', '13/01/2021']

# Conversion of dates
df['data'] = pd.to_datetime(df['data'], format='%d/%m/%Y')
new_dates = pd.to_datetime(list_dates, format='%d/%m/%Y')

# Set datetime column as index and append new dates
df = df.set_index('data')
df = df.reindex(df.index.append(new_dates)).sort_index()

# Interpolate with method='time'
df['value'] = df['value'].interpolate(method='time')
```

Output:

```
>>> df
            value
2021-01-01   10.0
2021-01-07   10.0
2021-01-12   15.0  # <- time interpolation
2021-01-13   16.0  # <- time interpolation
2021-01-14   17.0  # <- changed from 10 to 17
2021-01-28   10.0
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply but that doesn't take into account the window right? so basically to get the 2021-01-12 value, I need to use only 2021-01-07, 2021-01-01 , 2021-01-14, 2021-01-28 to get the interpolation (not all the dataframe)

Comment: Your comment is unclear for me. To get the interpolation of 2021-01-12 you need only 2021-01-07 and 2021-01-14, right? Maybe give an example where values are not constant (10) may help.

Comment: think about a dataframe that has thousands of dates, simply using interpolate will take into account all values no? I only want to use a window of 4 (2 before, 2 after)

Comment: Pandas search only NaN values (which is really fast) and interpolate using enclose values (one before, one after). Replace your 10s by [20, 10, 17, 40]. What should be the interpolate values for [2021-01-12, 2021-02-13]?